# Could we today ignore widths smaller then 960 px?

Tags: css, responsive-design

```
body{
    max-width:1366px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

My website is `1366px` max width.

My phone (two years old) is 1920 x 1080.

Phones of my friends are simmilar - 960px width and higher.

I cannot find any phone on my environment with smaller resolution.

On the other side, Google has its Chrome module for responsive checking  (console and click on mobile icon) with widths like `360 - 375 - 412 - 414 - 768px`.

Simmilar sitation is on many web sites for that purpose - for example - https://www.responsinator.com/

My dillemma is - do I need to change any on my website?

It suits very fine on 960px without any intervention.

Could I just ignore the Google's widths smaller then 960px?

Is there any real possibility that in today's world someone has a phone with 360 px width?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your target. Check out [this page](http://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats) for one set of data on screen resolutions out in the wild. Also understand that you and your friends are probably a bit of a skewed sample when it comes to mobile devices, and a flagship or even mid-range device from 2 years ago is still way ahead of low end devices being sold today.

Comment: Depends purely on target. I am still creating each website for each resolution, but I am not going under 320 pixels since iPhone 4 is the only one I can think of which uses specific resolution.

Comment: according to your link in Europe, january 2018, there are 18.32% phones with `360x640px` screen size. It's very hard to believe. Is that data about sold devices in that period or maybe about all existing devices with that resolution?

Comment: see https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/98985/why-the-360x640px-resolution-is-currently-the-most-used-one

Comment: Huh, I was thought that the number of pixels is an ordinary simple thing

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support maximum device compatibility you can try following media query

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is - `could we ignore the sizes below 960px in today's world?`. Could you find in your environment any live example with the phone of 440px, for example?

Comment: According to bootstrap media query and device width , If you ignore small devices then you can use 992px

Comment: Could you give me a link with that bootstrap data, pls?